# Magento 2: Controller issue

Tags: magento2

I have code in the controller 
eg:

```
if($token=='')
        {           
          echo 'token not found'; exit; 
        } else {
          echo $lead; exit; 
        }
```

But need to return this

```
 public function execute()
    {


        if(isset($getCookie)){
            $lead = $this->api->getleadDataForm('COOKIE', $getCookie,$allfield);
            $token=$this->api->getToken();
        }
        if($token=='')
        {           
          $response = 'token not found'; 
        } else {
          $response = $lead; 
        }       
        return $response;
    }
```

But the return value code is not working

Getting a response in js

```
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 

   jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery.post('<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>abc/index/data', data, 
              function(response)
    { alert(response);});  });
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: please add your code FUll which class you have inserted in constructor

Comment: updated question

Comment: Please format your code properly...

Comment: Formated code. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        if(isset($getCookie)){
            $lead = $this->api->getleadDataForm('COOKIE', $getCookie,$allfield);
            $token=$this->api->getToken();
        }
        if($token=='')
        {           
          $response = 'token not found'; 
        } else {
          $response = $lead; 
        } 
        return $result->setData($response);
    }
}
```